# PHP comparar String de un array con otro y si coinciden generar nuevo array

Tags: php, array-bidimensional

Tengo un array ***($matPos)*** que contiene Strings.

Tengo un segundo array ***($matTotal)*** que contiene pares clave => valor, en este caso *material => cantidad* (String, int)

Tengo dos bucles **for each** anidados, con los que pretendo recorrer ambos vectores, para que los **materiales que coinciden en ambos vectores**, y **tienen cantdiad distinto de 0**, me los meta en un nuevo array ***($matPart )***, que también será de *tipo clave=>valor*, y alamcenará **material=>cantidad**
Además, he implementado un contador ***($matCantidad)***, para saber cuantos elementos contiene el nuevo array.

```
$matPos=array("hidratacion","comida","mapa","brujula","gps","movil","dcs","botiquin","manta","linterna","cuerda");


$matTotal =[
    "linterna"=>$linternaT,
    "hidratacion"=>$hidratacionT,
    "comida"=>$comidaT,
    "roparec"=>$roparecT,
    "silbato"=>$silbatoT,
    "bocina"=>$bocinaT,
    "movil"=>$movilT,
    "mechero"=>$mecheroT,];

    $matCantidad=0;

    foreach($matTotal as $material=>$cantidad)
    {
        foreach ($matPos as $valor) 
        {
            if ($valor == $material)    
            {
                if($cantidad!=0)
                {
                    $matPart = [$material =>$cantidad];
                    $matCantidad++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

La cantidad de elementos alamcenada en la variable matCantidad es distinto de 0, así que supongo que el array clave valor está bien.

El problema viene cuando accedo a los valores de este array generado ***($matPart)***, ya que **no me muestra nada por pantalla**. La forma de acceso es:

```
$matInvernalesPart[0][0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No hay que complicarse tanto para acumular coincidencias de arrays. Con [in_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.in-array.php) y un par de condicionales, harán este código más sencillo:

```
$matPart = array();
foreach($matTotal as $key=>$value) {
    if (in_array($key, $matPos) and ($value != 0)) {
        $matPart[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

Para saber la cantidad de elementos: `$matCantidad = count($matPart);`

Comment: Nota. El código de la respuesta genera un array unidimensional. Si quieres uno bidimensional entonces: `$matPart[] = [$key=>$value];`

Comment: y la declaración del array bidimensional es igual o seria $matPat =array(array()); ? y apra acceder a los valores $matPart[$i][$j]?